# minikube failed to start : Exiting due to HOST_JUJU_LOCK_PERMISSION

Tags: docker, kubernetes, devops, docker-swarm, minikube

i wanted to install minikube and after the start command a got the following error text :

```
  minikube v1.26.1 on Ubuntu 22.04
❗  minikube skips various validations when --force is supplied; this may lead to unexpected behavior
✨  Using the docker driver based on existing profile
  The "docker" driver should not be used with root privileges. If you wish to continue as root, use --force.
  If you are running minikube within a VM, consider using --driver=none:
    https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/drivers/none/
  Tip: To remove this root owned cluster, run: sudo minikube delete
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Pulling base image ...
✋  Stopping node "minikube"  ...
  Powering off "minikube" via SSH ...
  Deleting "minikube" in docker ...
  StartHost failed, but will try again: boot lock: unable to open /tmp/juju-mke11f63b5835bf422927bf558fccac7a21a838f: permission denied
  Failed to start docker container. Running "minikube delete" may fix it: boot lock: unable to open /tmp/juju-mke11f63b5835bf422927bf558fccac7a21a838f: permission denied

❌  Exiting due to HOST_JUJU_LOCK_PERMISSION: Failed to start host: boot lock: unable to open /tmp/juju-mke11f63b5835bf422927bf558fccac7a21a838f: permission denied
  Suggestion: Run 'sudo sysctl fs.protected_regular=0', or try a driver which does not require root, such as '--driver=docker'
  Related issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/6391
```

Comment: The  log says " Failed to start docker container. Running "minikube delete" may fix it: boot lock: unable to open /tmp/juju-mke11f63b5835bf422927bf558fccac7a21a838f: permission denied"

Comment: Is this a Minikube which you are trying to test in some ubuntu system?

Comment: @sidharthvijayakumar yes im trying to start minikube on ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried this command and it worked for me :

```
minikube delete && minikube start
```

Comment: Did u run the command which i gave ??

Answer (score 6):

Can you run the below command if this Minikube is installed in a lower environment ?

```
rm /tmp/juju-*
```

[unable to open /tmp/juju-kubeconfigUpdate: permission denied](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/5660)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solved it. I guess it happens if you switch between non-root and root users.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following command:

```
sudo sysctl fs.protected_regular=0
```

Answer (score 0):

**Title:** Permission Denied Error in Minikube Deployment with Ansible: HOST_JUJU_LOCK_PERMISSION

**Issue Description:**
I encountered a problem while working with Ansible to deploy an application in Minikube. The specific error message was:

*Exiting due to HOST_JUJU_LOCK_PERMISSION: Failed to start host: boot lock: unable to open /tmp/juju-mke11f63b5835bf422927bf558fccac7a21a838f: permission denied  Suggestion: Run 'sudo sysctl fs.protected_regular=0', or try a driver which does not require root, such as '--driver=docker'*

**Solution:**
I added a task in Ansible to remove temporary files to resolve this issue. Here is the task for reference:

```
- name: Remove Temp Files
  become: true
  shell: "sudo rm /tmp/juju-* -rf"
```

Alternatively, you can execute the following command directly in your environment:

```
sudo rm /tmp/juju-* -rf
```

**Explanation:**

The error HOST_JUJU_LOCK_PERMISSION indicates a problem with file permissions while attempting to start the Minikube host. The suggested solution is to run the command sudo sysctl fs.protected_regular=0 or consider using a driver that does not require root privileges, such as --driver=docker. The provided Ansible task or the direct command helps remove temporary files that might be causing the permission issues.

**By implementing this solution, you should be able to overcome the permission denied error and proceed with your Minikube deployment using Ansible.**